# Edit fields in csv files using bash

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have a bunch of csv files that need "cleaning".
Specifically, there is a column that contains timestamp values, however some lines have a value of '1' instead. 
What I wish to do, is replace those 1's with the last valid (timestamp) value, i.e. replace the value of i-th line with that of that of line i-1.

I provide a sample of the file

```
URL192.168.2.2,420042,20/07/2015 09:40:00,168430081,168430109
URL192.168.2.2,420042,20/07/2015 09:40:00,3232236038,3232236034
URL192.168.2.2,420042,                  1,168430081,168430109
URL192.168.2.2,420042,20/07/2015 09:40:01,3232236038,3232236034
```

So in this example, the `1` must be replaced with `20/07/2015 09:40:00`. I tried it using `awk` but couldn't nail it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming no commas in the other fields, an awk program like this should work:

```
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
$3!=1 { prev = $3 }
$3==1 { $3 = prev }
      { print }
```

Warning: this is untested code.

The first line sets the field separator to a comma, for both input and output. The second line saves the timestamp of every row that has a timestamp in the third field. The third line writes the most recently saved timestamp to every row that doesn't have a timestamp in the third field. And the fourth line writes every input line, whether modified or not, to the output.

Let me know how you get on.